# Better type inference for multiple parameter lists in Dotty

Tags: scala, type-inference, fold, dotty, scala-3

What change in type inference brought [better](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10642) type inference for `Option#fold` in Dotty? For example

```
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> Option(5).fold(Left("err"))(Right(_))
val res0: Either[String, Int] = Right(5)
```

whilst in Scala 2.13.3 it errors

```
scala> Option(5).fold(Left("err"))(Right(_))
                                        ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : scala.util.Right[Nothing,Int]
        required: scala.util.Left[String,Nothing]
```

This seems to be related to [multiple parameter lists](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9262#issuecomment-292436839) such as `Option#fold`

```
fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B
```

which in Scala 2 work as follows

> this behaviour or inference runs pretty deeply through the way that
> applications are type checked, and it is relied upon in APIs like
> foldLeft, which allow the constraints accumulated by considering the
> first argument list to allow you to omit types in the second argument
> list.

however it backfires in the above example because the "accumulated constraint" applied to second parameter list is `Left[String,Nothing]`.

Comment: Yup, [here](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/overload-resolution.html) it is. I suppose those changes also impact type inference